# Bash как экранировать спецсимвол <?

Tags: bash, символы, экранирование

Как экранировать символ < в bash?

строчка скрипта:
mysqldump -u root -pA<13

Comment: А обычным символом экранирования (бэкслэш) `mysqldump -u root -pA\<13` не получается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте кавычки - одинарные или двойные:

```
mysqldump -u root -p"A<13"
```

Comment: точно, спасибо)